# Unable to download a PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf

I have tried different ways of implementing the method but nothing is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, provident perferendis. Adipisci beatae libero nihil eaque a nobis nulla pariatur itaque sunt, magni unde vitae corporis deleniti officia molestias nemo! </p>
    <button onclick="createPDF()">Create PDF</button>

</body>
<script> 
    function createPDF(){
        import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

        // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
        const doc = new jsPDF();
        var html = document.getElementById("p").innerHTML;

        doc.text(html, 10, 10);
        doc.save("a4.pdf");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

This is the code I have so far. I saw a YouTube tutorial on this and that person made it work using the exact way I've implemented it here. However, when I try to run it, it doesn't work. I've even tried adding the CDN for JQuery and it still doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Would like to add that I'm testing on the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console? Or what else happens when you run the code? "doesn't work" isn't a meaningful or informative description of the problem. P.s. I can't see how jQuery would help here, what gave you that idea?

Comment: Also can you link to the tutorial? Then maybe we can check whether you really have copied it exactly or not

Comment: @ADyson for JQuery, I just assumed it was something that was required because a few others had it in their versions on this website. The documentation doesn't say it's required, however. The post has been answered and their solution works and I think it was mostly due to the script tag not working properly.

Comment: `I just assumed it was something that was required`...why assume anything? You can the actual requirements [easily enough](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html). You're correct that it doesn't say it's required. Guesswork and assumptions, or including code "just in case" leads to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and no-one wants that. Glad the issue was resolved anyway :-)

Comment: @Sal, Please mark either of the two answers as resolved, check the checkbox on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

1. Change to script tag source to: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"
2. Remove the import statement in createPDF function.

Final script looked like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, provident perferendis. Adipisci beatae libero nihil eaque a nobis nulla pariatur itaque sunt, magni unde vitae corporis deleniti officia molestias nemo! </p>
    <button onclick="createPDF()">Create PDF</button>

</body>
    <script> 
    function createPDF(){

        // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
        const doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
        doc.save("a4.pdf");
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive error:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

This error is corrected by specifying  `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. So remove `import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"`, and use script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

You can learn more about this plugin by following [this link](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html).

```js
function createPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
    doc.save("a4.pdf");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, provident perferendis. Adipisci beatae libero nihil eaque a nobis nulla pariatur itaque sunt, magni unde vitae corporis deleniti officia molestias nemo!</p>
<button onclick="createPDF()">Create PDF</button>
```